# Why is the space of compactly supported smooth functions contained in the Schwartz space?

Tags: functional-analysis, schwartz-space

The Schwartz space is defined as $\mathcal{S} = \left\{ f \in C^\infty : \|f\|_{(N,\alpha)} < \infty \text{ for all } N,\alpha \right\}$, where the family of semi-norms $\|\cdot\|_{(N,\alpha)}$ is given by
$$
\|f\|_{(N,\alpha)} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} (1+|x|)^N |\partial^\alpha f(x)|.
$$

In Folland's Real Analysis, he states that "clearly, $C_c^\infty \subset \mathcal{S}$. It is not immediately clear to me why this is true. Of course, any $C_c^\infty$ function vanishes at infinity, but I don't see why this would have to be faster than any power of $|x|$.

I first thought to consider $\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} (1+|x|)^N| \partial^\alpha f(x)|$, which is of indeterminate type $\infty\cdot 0$. Recasting as a fraction $(1+|x|)^N/|\partial^\alpha f(x)|^{-1}$ and applying L'Hopital's rule, the quantity $|\partial^\alpha f(x)|^{-1}$ will always tend to $\pm\infty$ no matter how many derivatives we take, but eventually $(1+|x|)^{N}$ would become finite even as $x \to \pm\infty$ and hence, the limit is finite. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: If f has compact support, the the function whose limit you are trying to compute is identically zero outside some bounded interval, so its limit at infinity is clearly zero. (I don't know what you did to "recast it as a fraction" but certainly the fraction you got makes no sense at all, as its denominator is zero quite often!)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Okay, I see now. I was just going on autopilot and not really thinking. I just saw that one term tends to infinity and the other tends to 0, but for some reason completely ignored that the partials are actually identically 0. Really silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> Of course, any $C_c^\infty$ function vanishes at infinity, but I don't see why this would have to be faster than any power of $|x|$.

The set $C_c^\infty$ is the space of compactly supported infinitely differentiable functions. "Compactly supported" implies it's $0$ outside of some compact set. All compact sets are bounded. Thus if $f\in C_c^\infty,$ then for some number $M$ you have for every $x>M$ or $x<-M,$ $f(x) = 0.$ If $f(x)$ reaches $0$ and then stays there as $x$ approaches $+\infty$ or $-\infty,$ then certainly it goes to $0$ faster than anything that doesn't do that.